# Get an element from a Hashtbl in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, hashtable

I'm quite new in OCaml so it's quite complicated for me to use right now an existing code but I unfortunately need it.

I've got a variable declared as follow:

```
val var_of_string : (string, int) Hashtbl.t
```

And I would like to get an element and display it inside a function.

```
let rec string_of_id n = match DynArray.get id_to_fml n with
    Lit -> (if n land 1 == 0 then
              string_of_int (Hashtbl.find var_of_string string_of_int(n))
            else 
              "-" ^ string_of_int (Hashtbl.find var_of_string string_of_int(n))
           )
  | And ids ->
      (match ids with
       [] -> "#true#"
     | _ -> "(" ^ String.concat " & " (List.map string_of_id ids) ^ ")")
  | Or ids ->
      (match ids with
       [] -> "#false#"
     | _ -> "(" ^ String.concat " | " (List.map string_of_id ids) ^ ")")
  | Dia (r, n) -> "<" ^ string_of_int r ^ ">" ^ string_of_id n
  | Box (r, n) -> "[" ^ string_of_int r ^ "]" ^ string_of_id n
  | True -> "true"
  | False -> "false"
```

Basically, the only important part is :

```
    Lit -> (if n land 1 == 0 then
              string_of_int (Hashtbl.find var_of_string string_of_int(n))
            else 
              "-" ^ string_of_int (Hashtbl.find var_of_string string_of_int(n))
           )
```

I've got an integer `n` (that can become a `string`) and I've got a hashtable `string ; int`. I would like to be able to get the element at the n-th case of the Hashtable but I don't know how to do this :/

I tried `Hashtbl.find var_of_string n`by looking at the [documentation](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Hashtbl.html) but I get this error message :

```
Error: The implementation syntax.ml does not match the interface syntax.cmi:
       Values do not match:
         val var_of_string : (int, string) Hashtbl.t
       is not included in
         val var_of_string : (string, int) Hashtbl.t
       File "syntax.ml", line 55, characters 4-17: Actual declaration
```

Looks like I do something in a wrong way, but I have no idea how to do it :/

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bad habit to use `(==)` for integer comparison. Use `(=)`, the structural comparison instead.  `(==)` is the physical comparison using pointers. For integers, they are the same, but generally they behave differently. Careless use of `(==)` will shoot your foot badly one day.

`val var_of_string : (string, int) Hashtbl.t`  is a table whose keys are `string`.  You can add/replace/remove/find `int` values using `string` keys.  In your code you do opposite: trying to find `string` values using `int` keys.  It is wrong.  You need a table, say, `string_of_var` of type `(int, string) Hashtbl.t` if you want to query the name of your variable from its id number.

One possible way is to build this reverse table from `var_of_string`.  It is easily done by iterating the bindings in `var_of_string` using `Hashtbl.iter`.  But if you could build `string_of_var` directly without using `var_of_string`, it would be better for code clarity and performance.  Without enough background we cannot tell which is the best for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your Hashtable has key a string and value an integer.

Hashtable.find has the following signature:

```
val find : ('a, 'b) t -> 'a -> 'b
```

see http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Hashtbl.html

you are attempting to use Hashtable.find on a value.

Comment: But ` Hashtbl.find var_of_string string_of_int(n)` is not working neither :/ I think I don't know how to use it at all :/

Basically in an other language, I would like to be able to use : 

string_of_int (Hashtbl.find var_of_string string_of_int(n))